# OpenCV Nodejs prepare image to OCR TesseractJS, remove dots

Tags: node.js, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to read data over Tesseract from image captured by webcamera. Here is example of used[image: Base image] image:

I'm working on nodejs server, and I tried a lot of technique in Jimp including doing invert/grayscale, using sharpening to image, or fiiltering specific colors /yellow/blue/ ... after all I build separated docker container using opencv4nodejs and apply few techniques to extract text from that image.

I need mostly big texts (so small one are not neccessary /also are not sharp on this image/). So I applied this:

```
const src = cv.imread('./970f5b45-9f24-41d5-91f0-ef3f8b9d8914.jpeg');
    
let src2 = src.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
let dst = src2.adaptiveThreshold(255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 12, 2);
let dst2 = dst.morphologyEx(cv.MORPH_OPEN)
```

After that I have this result, which is almost ready for reading by OCR, problem is a lot of dots in that image. Is there any chance to remove that dots, but keep quality of result (readable texts) in opencv, or other technique?

Result is right now:

[image: Parsed image]

Is it possible to extract just texts from that result? If I use this result in ocr by tesseract, it takes really a long time to extract text, and there is a huge amount of weird characters (probably because of dots/shapes).